# Restrict CSV record length to 100 characters in xslt

Tags: csv, xslt

I have an xslt to convert xml to CSV. But I don't want records in output to be more than 100 characters. Below is my xslt, can some one help me to restrict each record of out put to 100 characters?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Positive_Pay_SVB"
    xmlns:this="urn:this-stylesheet" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'&#x20;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/>


    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">

        <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Entry/wd:Payments_group"/>


    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry/wd:Payments_group">

        <xsl:variable name="Paymentamount" select="translate(normalize-space(translate(wd:Payment_Total_Amount,'.','')),'','')"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="wd:CF_Account_number_HSBC_Canada"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring('0000000000', 1 + string-length(wd:Check_Number)), wd:Check_Number)"/>



        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring('0000000000', 1 + string-length($Paymentamount)), $Paymentamount)"/>



        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Payment_Date"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Payment_Payee/@wd:Descriptor"/>


        <xsl:value-of select='$linefeed'/>

     </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always restrict the output length of a value with

```
substring(value,1,100)
```

If you have multiple `xsl:value-of` that you want to restrict, concatenate them and then apply the above expression:

```
substring(concat(value1,value2,...),1,100)
```

So applied to your template, this could look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry/wd:Payments_group">    
    <xsl:variable name="Paymentamount" select="translate(normalize-space(translate(wd:Payment_Total_Amount,'.','')),'','')"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="substring(wd:CF_Account_number_HSBC_Canada,1,100)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(substring('0000000000', 1 + string-length(wd:Check_Number)), wd:Check_Number, concat(substring('0000000000', 1 + string-length($Paymentamount)), $Paymentamount), wd:Payment_Date),1,100)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="substring(wd:Payment_Payee/@wd:Descriptor,1,100)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select='$linefeed'/>

</xsl:template>
```